# How to figure out which decode command to use to decode a encoded string with PHP

Tags: php, encoding, decoding

I have 2 encoded  string 
*021020211002111010120220010202110001100011010010121110211010110201100010201* and *41424320313233205465737420546573742054657374* .

I dont know which encoding command has been used to encode them.  I want to detect how the 2 strings has been encoded?

I have found this command.      `mb_detect_encoding($str)`  But I am not sure how to use it to figure out the encoding .

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding` is related to _character encoding_, but it appears that is not what you are dealing with here in the first place.

Comment: _“I dont know which encoding command has been used to encode them. I want to detect how the 2 strings has been encoded?”_ - that is likely pretty much impossible to determine, based on just the info you have given so far.

Comment: Thats the trouble.  If I would knew how they have been encoded I could decode them with that command. Is there any way to find out the encoding

Comment: The first one is groups of five digits of ASCII encoded in base 3, the second is groups of two digits encoded in base 16: https://3v4l.org/cjfrO

Comment: Thank you iainn for your response and decoding solution on the link.  Can you advice how did you figure out about   encoding techniques i.e 1st one with ASCII and 2nd one with base 16